# dumping and modifying keyboard firmware

Tags: firmware

is theoretically possible to dump the keyboard firmware of a laptop, modify it and reflash it to  make the keyboard works not properly ?
I don't know even if the laptop keyboard has a firmware.
Without accessing phisically to any chip. Just by software.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if laptop keyboards have firmware on their own, but keyboard input is usually processed by the embedded controller (EC), for example for handling hardware-related buttons such as brightness control. This firmware is often included as part of BIOS updates (and can be extracted from them).

For example, at Recon 2011 Alexandre Gazet presented a talk [*Sticky fingers & KBC Custom Shop*](https://recon.cx/2011/schedule/events/102.en.html) which described analyzing a "keyboard controller" (but more likely EC) firmware to embed a backdoor code which would infect the host BIOS's SMM handler and (in theory) take over the machine on the lowest level. I was not able to find the English slides or video of the talk but there is a [French paper](https://www.sstic.org/media/SSTIC2011/SSTIC-actes/sticky_fingers_and_kbc_custom_shop/SSTIC2011-Article-sticky_fingers_and_kbc_custom_shop-gazet_1.pdf) from SSTIC 2011.

It in turn refers to the 27C3 (2010) talk [*The Hidden Nemesis: Backdooring Embedded Controllers*](http://events.ccc.de/congress/2010/Fahrplan/events/4174.en.html) by Ralf-Philipp Weinmann which instead the EC into a keylogger. Video of the talk [is available](https://media.ccc.de/v/27c3-4174-en-the_hidden_nemesis).